# Some references on Dh4 point group ans superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, representation-theory, superconductivity

Just wondering if anyone has any lecture notes or books/chapters which cover the representations of Dh4 CLEARLY. In particular, the form factors of superconductors are labeled with the representations of this group and I'd like to know more about superconductors and these representations.

It does not need to be completely mathematically rigorous, but that is preferable over a handwavy source. It is hard to ask for that sweet spot us physicists tend to like: intuitive with some rigor. Worth a shot though...